# LINQ query not equal

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Afternoon,
How would i set this as not equal to? I am basically trying to say, if p.catrgory is not equal to one of the categories in the database.

```
 p.category == dc.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == p.category).Name
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dc.Categories.Where(c => c.Name = p.category).Any();
```

it will return true if exists, so, use, `!` operator

```
!dc.Categories.Where(c => c.Name = p.category).Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

`p.Category` is not in the DB?

```
var exists == !dc.Categories.Any(c => c.Name == p.category)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the var be notExists since you're inverting the sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
p.category == dc.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == p.category).Name
```

to

```
p.category == dc.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name != p.category).Name
```

**if p.category is not equal to one of the categories in the databas**